# Blending in 3D graphics

Tags: directx

I studying DirectX blending. Please explain what is Src and Dest. For example I have drawn scene - it's Src as I suppose. And on this scene I now puting box - it's Dest in blending, as I guess. And I process blending my previous scene Src with my box Dest. Or what?

Answer (score 2):

The buffer starts with the color/skybox/whatever you've cleared it with.

After that, for each render pass

- sourceValue is the value output by the fragment shader.
- destinationValue is the value already in the buffer.

So you're choosing how to blend the thing you're rendering (src) with what's already been put in the buffer (dst) by any previous passes.